# usb serial driver and ATE1 E0

Tags: linux-device-driver

I am writing an USB serial adapter device driver. The kernel is 3.17.4. The driver works fine except that the kernel opens the adapter twice and writes some commands when the adapter is plugged in. Here are dump_stack() for the driver's open() and write().

1st open() and write(). The kernel writes "ATE1 E0" three times.

```
<4>[19964.897631] Call Trace:
<4>[19964.897642]  [<ffffffff8173f929>] dump_stack+0x45/0x56
<4>[19964.897649]  [<ffffffffa04aa1ef>] c0087_open+0x2f/0x160    [usb_com_1p_driver]
<4>[19964.897654]  [<ffffffff81744bb2>] ? down_write+0x12/0x40
<4>[19964.897661]  [<ffffffff81566f75>] serial_port_activate+0x65/0x90
<4>[19964.897667]  [<ffffffff8145e864>] ? tty_port_tty_set+0x64/0xa0
<4>[19964.897671]  [<ffffffff8145edf9>] tty_port_open+0x89/0xe0
<4>[19964.897675]  [<ffffffff81567bf3>] serial_open+0x33/0x70
<4>[19964.897679]  [<ffffffff814560eb>] tty_open+0x17b/0x700
<4>[19964.897684]  [<ffffffff8149cf72>] ? kobj_lookup+0x112/0x170
<4>[19964.897690]  [<ffffffff81211017>] chrdev_open+0xb7/0x1a0
<4>[19964.897694]  [<ffffffff81210f60>] ? cdev_put+0x30/0x30
<4>[19964.897698]  [<ffffffff81209832>] do_dentry_open+0x1d2/0x320
<4>[19964.897702]  [<ffffffff81209b61>] finish_open+0x31/0x50
<4>[19964.897706]  [<ffffffff8121cd7c>] do_last+0xc0c/0x11d0
<4>[19964.897710]  [<ffffffff81217bd8>] ? inode_permission+0x18/0x50
<4>[19964.897713]  [<ffffffff812180e9>] ? link_path_walk+0x99/0xee0
<4>[19964.897717]  [<ffffffff8121d40b>] path_openat+0xcb/0x6d0
<4>[19964.897722]  [<ffffffff8121e2ad>] do_filp_open+0x4d/0xc0
<4>[19964.897726]  [<ffffffff812178db>] ? getname_flags+0x4b/0x180
<4>[19964.897731]  [<ffffffff8122b01e>] ? __alloc_fd+0x7e/0x120
<4>[19964.897735]  [<ffffffff8120b61b>] do_sys_open+0x13b/0x250
<4>[19964.897738]  [<ffffffff8120b74e>] SyS_open+0x1e/0x20
<4>[19964.897743]  [<ffffffff81746ae9>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b


<4>[19965.026562]  [<ffffffff8173f929>] dump_stack+0x45/0x56
<4>[19965.026569]  [<ffffffffa04aa094>] c0087_write+0x24/0x100 [usb_com_1p_driver]
<4>[19965.026575]  [<ffffffff81567890>] serial_write+0x50/0xc0
<4>[19965.026581]  [<ffffffff814584e5>] n_tty_write+0x495/0x560
<4>[19965.026586]  [<ffffffff810c2850>] ? wake_up_state+0x20/0x20
<4>[19965.026590]  [<ffffffff81454a04>] tty_write+0x174/0x300
<4>[19965.026594]  [<ffffffff81458050>] ? process_echoes+0x70/0x70
<4>[19965.026599]  [<ffffffff8120c597>] vfs_write+0xb7/0x1f0
<4>[19965.026603]  [<ffffffff8120d1c5>] SyS_write+0x55/0xd0
<4>[19965.026608]  [<ffffffff81746ae9>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
```

2nd open() and write(). The kernel writes "7e 0 78 f0 7e" twice.

```
<4>[19977.011908] Call Trace:
<4>[19977.011918]  [<ffffffff8173f929>] dump_stack+0x45/0x56
<4>[19977.011925]  [<ffffffffa04aa1ef>] c0087_open+0x2f/0x160 [usb_com_1p_driver]
<4>[19977.011930]  [<ffffffff81744bb2>] ? down_write+0x12/0x40
<4>[19977.011936]  [<ffffffff81566f75>] serial_port_activate+0x65/0x90
<4>[19977.011941]  [<ffffffff8145e864>] ? tty_port_tty_set+0x64/0xa0
<4>[19977.011945]  [<ffffffff8145edf9>] tty_port_open+0x89/0xe0
<4>[19977.011949]  [<ffffffff81567bf3>] serial_open+0x33/0x70
<4>[19977.011952]  [<ffffffff814560eb>] tty_open+0x17b/0x700
<4>[19977.011958]  [<ffffffff81211017>] chrdev_open+0xb7/0x1a0
<4>[19977.011961]  [<ffffffff81210f60>] ? cdev_put+0x30/0x30
<4>[19977.011965]  [<ffffffff81209832>] do_dentry_open+0x1d2/0x320
<4>[19977.011968]  [<ffffffff81209b61>] finish_open+0x31/0x50
<4>[19977.011972]  [<ffffffff8121cd7c>] do_last+0xc0c/0x11d0
<4>[19977.011975]  [<ffffffff81217bd8>] ? inode_permission+0x18/0x50
<4>[19977.011979]  [<ffffffff812180e9>] ? link_path_walk+0x99/0xee0
<4>[19977.011983]  [<ffffffff8121d40b>] path_openat+0xcb/0x6d0
<4>[19977.011986]  [<ffffffff81455de0>] ? tty_release+0x4c0/0x650
<4>[19977.011990]  [<ffffffff8121e2ad>] do_filp_open+0x4d/0xc0
<4>[19977.011993]  [<ffffffff812178db>] ? getname_flags+0x4b/0x180
<4>[19977.011998]  [<ffffffff8122b01e>] ? __alloc_fd+0x7e/0x120
<4>[19977.012002]  [<ffffffff8120b61b>] do_sys_open+0x13b/0x250
<4>[19977.012025]  [<ffffffff8120b74e>] SyS_open+0x1e/0x20
<4>[19977.012031]  [<ffffffff81746ae9>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b



<4>[19977.026758]  [<ffffffff8173f929>] dump_stack+0x45/0x56
<4>[19977.026766]  [<ffffffffa04aa094>] c0087_write+0x24/0x100 [usb_com_1p_driver]
<4>[19977.026772]  [<ffffffff81567890>] serial_write+0x50/0xc0
<4>[19977.026777]  [<ffffffff814584e5>] n_tty_write+0x495/0x560
<4>[19977.026782]  [<ffffffff810c2850>] ? wake_up_state+0x20/0x20
<4>[19977.026786]  [<ffffffff81454a04>] tty_write+0x174/0x300
<4>[19977.026789]  [<ffffffff81458050>] ? process_echoes+0x70/0x70
<4>[19977.026794]  [<ffffffff8120c597>] vfs_write+0xb7/0x1f0
<4>[19977.026797]  [<ffffffff8120d1c5>] SyS_write+0x55/0xd0
<4>[19977.026802]  [<ffffffff81746ae9>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
```

Anybody knows what happens here?

Thanks!

Comment: The kernel isn't doing it on its own, it's doing it on behalf of some process, probably ModemManager or something like that.

Comment: AT looks like the start of the hayes AT command set: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set . @hobbs is likely right, something in userspace (udev rule?) is probing your device to see if its a modem.

Answer (score 4):

It is the ModemManager that sends those commands. After stopping ModemManager there are no more commands to the adapter.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to update your question with the answer.

Comment: On `systemd` distributions (most in 2019), one can use `systemctl stop ModemManager` and `systemctl disable ModemManager`.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu the following command solves the problem:

```
sudo stop modemmanager
```

You can the start it again by:

```
sudo start modemmanager
```